# Add a shortcut to do something through photos app with React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, shortcut

I want to make a shortcut through the photos app to do something when the user clicks it. Is there a documentation somewhere I can read to do this?

[image]

There would be a button from my app to do something when the user presses it, represented by the new thing square in the shortcuts menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a 3rd party library like: react-native-share-menu

I'm not aware of how else to achieve that with vanilla.